# Making multiple round trips vs using a temp table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqlperformance

I need to save a list of records with a few columns. I got two ways to do that.

1. I can simply create a list of that element and execute the stored procedure multiple times from within the code

   foreach(TestInfo test in lstTestInfo)
        {//execute the stored procedure}
2. I can build a string and send it to the database where I can split it and store it in a temp table and insert it there with a single round trip

Though this is not a serious issue...i want some insights.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to look at it. 1. Do what is easy vs 2. Do what is correct?
The first option is easy but not the one which will give you a long term solution. Sooner or later you will realize that it is not yeilding the right performance and its the most trivial way to do this. This may work well when you have few users and everything setup on one machine.

The second approach however not only reduce the wire transfers also minimize the calls to database. You are talking about executing a SP that means connection will be involved.. every call to DB is overhead and we should try to minimize that. If you are having a load balanced environment with n-tier deployment, you will be stuck calling DB on another server if you go with option #1.

I would choose Option 2. It will take little bit more time to implement but will save my efforts later.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple. Start with the the solution that you most easily can implement in a robust way, which I believe is the first one.

Then you can test if the performance is good enough, and reconsider the implementation if you have problems with it.

Comment: Actually I have been doing the first method...but now I m concerned about performance...

Answer (score 1):

If you try to implement second option, the length of string itself can be hinderance. There is only so much data you an send. More the data lesser you solution is effective.

More over making multiple calls(solution 1) to the DB is also an overhead. You could also mess up transactions assuming multiple cells are dependent on updation of others.

decide for yourself, its a tradeoff which you need to make.

Comment: Can you not create an insert/update statement from your application and execute it? Unless you insist on writing a proc to do insert/update

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple use a single connection and command to pass data efficiently. To can use other complex techniques, but I don't think will will offer much benefit and will make a mess of your sproc.

```
public void UpdateUserItems(Guid userId, string[] items)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring..."))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into UserItems(UserId, Items) values (@UserId, @Items)"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
            foreach(string item in items)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", Item;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently ask question and there are many possible answers. Have you, for example, considered [multiple optional parameters? [This article by Joe Celko](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/values%28%29-and-long-parameter-lists/) covers this option and also provides links to the 'classic' articles on the subject by Erland Sommarskog.